# Why does RNN always output 1

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) for forecasting, but for some weird reason, it always outputs 1. Here I explain this with a toy example as:

**Example** 
Consider a matrix `M` of dimensions (360, 5), and a vector `Y` which contains rowsum of `M`. Now, using RNN, I want to predict `Y` from `M`. Using `rnn` `R` package, I trained model as

```
   library(rnn) 
    M <- matrix(c(1:1800),ncol=5,byrow = TRUE) # Matrix (say features) 
    Y <- apply(M,1,sum) # Output equls to row sum of M
    mt <- array(c(M),dim=c(NROW(M),1,NCOL(M))) # matrix formatting as [samples, timesteps, features]
    yt <- array(c(Y),dim=c(NROW(M),1,NCOL(Y))) # formatting
    model <- trainr(X=mt,Y=yt,learningrate=0.5,hidden_dim=10,numepochs=1000) # training
```

One strange thing I observed while training is that epoch error is always 4501. Ideally, epoch error should decrease with the increase in epochs.

Next, I created a test dataset with the same structure as above one as:

```
M2 <- matrix(c(1:15),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE)
mt2 <- array(c(M2),dim=c(NROW(M2),1,NCOL(M2)))
predictr(model,mt2)
```

With prediction, I always get the output as 1.
 What can be the reason for the constant epoch error and the same output?

## UPDATE # 1

Answer provided by @Barker does not work on my problem. To make it open, here I share minimalistic data via dropbox links as [traindata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6u4dsjkfbef9pxl/train.csv?dl=0), [testadata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnmdvppvs1xfkii/test.csv?dl=0), and my  `R` code as.

Data details: column 'power' is response variable which is a function of temperature, humidity, and power consumed on previous days from  day1 to day 14.

```
normalize_data <- function(x){
  normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
  return(normalized)
}

#read test and train data
traindat <- read.csv(file = "train.csv")
testdat <- read.csv(file = "test.csv")
# column "power" is response variable and remaining are predictors
# predictors in  traindata
trainX <- traindat[,1:dim(traindat)[2]-1]
# response of train data
trainY <- traindat$power
# arrange data acc. to RNN as [samples,time steps, features]
tx <- array(as.matrix(trainX), dim=c(NROW(trainX), 1, NCOL(trainX)))
tx <- normalize_data(tx) # normalize data in range of [0,1]
ty <- array(trainY, dim=c(NROW(trainY), 1, NCOL(trainY))) # arrange response acc. to predictors
# train model
model <- trainr(X = tx, Y = ty, learningrate = 0.08, hidden_dim = 6, numepochs = 400)

# predictors in test data
testX <- testdat[,1:dim(testdat)[2]-1]
testX <- normalize_data(testX) # normalize data in range of [0,1]
#testY <- testdat$power
# arrange data acc. to RNN as [samples,time steps, features]
tx2 <- array(as.matrix(testX), dim=c(NROW(testX), 1, NCOL(testX))) # predict
pred <- predictr(model,tx2)
pred
```

I varied parameters `learning rate, hidden_dim, numepochs`, but still it either results in 0.9 or 1.

Comment: The simplest reason is that your learning rate is too high, or that the model just doesn't fit the data.

Comment: I find your data problematic. First off the data are too small to debug.  Even a linear model may struggle given a training data set with 16 columns and 37 rows, but a neural net? Forget about it. Your data don't seem to be in order other wise your lags for each row would be the same as the prior rows, just shifted over one column. RNNs need the data in order.  Finally, why are you using lags as features anyways?  The whole point of RNNs is the "memory" aspect that makes it remember prior data.  If you are feeding the prior values in anyways, you made your network more complicated for nothing.

Comment: @Barker, I got your point! But I still face problems with the time-series data modeling acc. to RNN input, I have  asked the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/42431720/3317829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most RNNs don't like data that don't have a constant mean.  One strategy for dealing with this is differencing the data. To see how this works, lets work with a base `R` time series `co2`.  This is a time series with a nice smooth seasonality and trend, so we should be able to forecast it.

[image: co2 time series]

For our model our input matrix is going to be the "seasonality" and "trend" of the `co2` time series, created using the `stl` decomposition.  So lets make our training and testing data as you did before and train the model (note I reduced the `numepochs` for runtime).  I will use all the data up to the last year and a half for training, and then use the last year and a half for testing:

```
#Create the STL decomposition
sdcomp <- stl(co2, s.window = 7)$time.series[,1:2]

Y <- window(co2, end = c(1996, 6))
M <- window(sdcomp, end = c(1996, 6))
#Taken from OP's code
mt <- array(c(M),dim=c(NROW(M),1,NCOL(M)))
yt <- array(c(Y),dim=c(NROW(M),1,NCOL(Y))) 
model <- trainr(X=mt,Y=yt,learningrate=0.5,hidden_dim=10,numepochs=100)
```

Now we can create our predictions on the last year of testing data:

```
M2 <- window(sdcomp, start = c(1996,7))
mt2 <- array(c(M2),dim=c(NROW(M2),1,NCOL(M2)))
predictr(model,mt2)

output:
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    1
 [3,]    1
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    1
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    1
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    1
[10,]    1
[11,]    1
[12,]    1
[13,]    1
[14,]    1
[15,]    1
[16,]    1
[17,]    1
[18,]    1
```

Ewe, it is all ones again, just like in your example.  Now lets try this again, but this time we will difference the data.  Since we are trying to make our predictions one and a half years out, we will use 18 as our differencing lag as those are the values we would know 18 months ahead of time.

```
dco2 <- diff(co2, 18)
sdcomp <- stl(dco2, s.window = "periodic")$time.series[,1:2]
plot(dco2)
```

[image: differenced c02 values]

Great, the trend is now gone so our neural net should be able to find the pattern better.  Lets try again with the new data.

```
Y <- window(dco2, end = c(1996, 6))
M <- window(sdcomp, end = c(1996, 6))

mt <- array(c(M),dim=c(NROW(M),1,NCOL(M)))
yt <- array(c(Y),dim=c(NROW(M),1,NCOL(Y)))
model <- trainr(X=mt,Y=yt,learningrate=0.5,hidden_dim=10,numepochs=100)

M2 <- window(sdcomp, start = c(1996,7))
mt2 <- array(c(M2),dim=c(NROW(M2),1,NCOL(M2)))
(preds <- predictr(model,mt2))

output:
              [,1]
 [1,] 9.999408e-01
 [2,] 9.478496e-01
 [3,] 6.101828e-08
 [4,] 2.615463e-08
 [5,] 3.144719e-08
 [6,] 1.668084e-06
 [7,] 9.972314e-01
 [8,] 9.999901e-01
 [9,] 9.999916e-01
[10,] 9.999916e-01
[11,] 9.999916e-01
[12,] 9.999915e-01
[13,] 9.999646e-01
[14,] 1.299846e-02
[15,] 3.114577e-08
[16,] 2.432247e-08
[17,] 2.586075e-08
[18,] 1.101596e-07
```

Ok, now there is something there!  Lets see how it compares to what were were trying to forecast, `dco2`:

[image: Overlay of plots]

Not ideal, but we but it is finding the general "up down" pattern of the data.  Now all you have to do is tinker with your learning rates and start optimizing with all those lovely hyper-parameters that make working with neural nets such a joy.  When it is working how you want, you can just take your final output and add back in the last 18 months of your training data.

Comment: Thanks, it works on this problem, but it does not work on my problem. Will be really thankful if you can go through the updated question and find where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From my review of the examples with the package (see `?trainr`) the inputs into the training function have to be binary. There are the functions `int2bin` and `bin2int` in the package.

I have not been able to get them to work correctly, but it appears conversion to binary is needed.

Comment: Can anyone verify that this is the case, i.e. that conversion to binary is needed for the rnn package. I have tried it out and I get some results without this conversion, although not impressively good.

Comment: @Erik--this vignette might help; there is a step where the arrays are reversed: 
               https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/vignettes/rnn.html

Comment: Thanks! In this example they convert to binary. My question was if this is strictly necessary. Anyway, I tried out and with carefully tuning the hyper-parameters, I get reasonable results using RNN even without converting to binary. So I guess the answer is that this is not strictly needed. However, I would still like to understand better how this conversion influences the results, and when it is needed. I guess it only applies to integers, and that for problems involving real numbers yo could just go ahead and train the RNN on the original data (normalized to be between 0 and 1).